# Any way to automate zoom meeting in a specific way?

Tags: conferencing, zoom-meeting

We are doing a meeting on zoom daily, where there is a list of about 30 participants. We have to handle the following situation manually right now by making someone host who has to manually do it:

Except one main speaker whose microphone we want to be on continuously unmute, the rest of the huge list of participants, we want them to speak one by one and we have a certain ordering who will speak first then next and next and so on.

Right now, the host has to look at the ordering list manually and then find out whose turn is to speak and then mute the already active participant and then unmute the one whose turn is next. This manually handling is very troublesome.

Is there any way to automate this process ? Any other alternative than zoom will also work.

Comment: The host can mute everyone (easy). Since people know the speaking order, ask them to unmute, speak, and mute.  That is very roughly the way we work in various meetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Zoom Host and a Zoom attender and have been using Zoom for almost as long as it has been out.

I researched my Host functions and there is no way to automate the order in which guests may speak - that is up to the Host to manage.

I also note from experience that Zoom does not create function out of dysfunction except as noted above, the Host can mute everyone to keep as much order as possible.

**Edit and Followup:**  Doing some review of my own notes, in a group of 30 people, statistically 6 to 10 of them will not really know how to run a meeting (this is a management skill). Consider having 8 people in your group run the meeting as a good host. That means 1 person runs a meeting every other month. This is time to prepare the strategy for managing as a good host. Try this.